# angular-cli: does css and script files load before app initially run?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I recently switched to angular-cli, and added some .js files in .angular-cli.json file under "scripts". Will those js files loaded before app initial run? same as put  before  tag?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: if you are on angular-cli 1.0.0 or later, those scripts will be added to a `scripts.bundle.js` file.

Comment: @AhmedMusallam yes, I am using angular-cli 1.0.2. I saw those scripts was in scripts.bundle.js file, and in its builded folder, I saw it included before main.bundle.js in index.html file, I assume it loaded before app initial runs.

Comment: Main.bundle.js has your app code, so yes, it is loaded before the app.

Comment: thanks @AhmedMusallam